# How to change bootstrap in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I am using this code to make a nav menu bar. As you can see the menu items are too close and it doesnt change the background color when hover. I want to edit the css for those items. What do I need to write in design.css ? Thankyou

[image: page]

header.php

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="navbar-header">
                      <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="#" style="margin-left: 50px;">Web</a>
                      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                      </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                         <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary', 'container'=>false, 'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav ml-auto','item_spacing'=>'preserve' )); ?>
                         <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn navbar-right" style="margin-left: 10px;">Login</button>
                         <button class="btn btn-default navbar-btn navbar-right" >Register</button>
                      </div>                     
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
         </div>
```

functions.php

```
//css
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.1.3', 'all');
     wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/design.css', array('bootstrap'), '0.0.1', 'null');

    //js
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
     wp_enqueue_script('bootstrapjs',get_template_directory_uri().'/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '4.1.3', true);
      wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/code.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
```

I tried this in design.css

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #000; /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I changed CSS Classes in Appearance, menus to navbar-default then this:

```
wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/design.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

.navbar-default  a:hover {
     background: #222;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```